# Neo4j Spatial: Supplied index configuration doesn't match stored config

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4j 1.8.2 with spatial 0.9.

I get the following exception when I try to get a handle to the spatial index on an existing graph that contains the index already:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Supplied index configuration:
{geometry_type=point, lon=lon, provider=spatial, lat=lat}
doesn't match stored config in a valid way:
{geometry_type=point, lon=lon, provider=spatial, lat=lat}
for 'testspatial'
    at org.neo4j.kernel.IndexManagerImpl.assertConfigMatches(IndexManagerImpl.java:156)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.IndexManagerImpl.findIndexConfig(IndexManagerImpl.java:137)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.IndexManagerImpl.getOrCreateIndexConfig(IndexManagerImpl.java:198)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.IndexManagerImpl.getOrCreateNodeIndex(IndexManagerImpl.java:301)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.IndexManagerImpl.forNodes(IndexManagerImpl.java:289)
    at TestSpatialIndexFetch.createSpatialIndex(TestSpatialIndexFetch.java:22)
    at TestSpatialIndexFetch.main(TestSpatialIndexFetch.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

If I delete the database, the index is created successfully. If I use this database now to get the index back, it fails.

Any ideas?

Sample test code:

```
public class TestSpatialIndexFetch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EmbeddedGraphDatabase db = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase("c://neo4jdbs//testindex");
        registerShutdownHook(db);
        Index<Node> index = createSpatialIndex(db, "testspatial");
    }

    private static Index<Node> createSpatialIndex(EmbeddedGraphDatabase db, String indexName) {
        return db.index().forNodes(indexName, SpatialIndexProvider.SIMPLE_POINT_CONFIG);
    }

    private static void registerShutdownHook( final GraphDatabaseService graphDb )
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                graphDb.shutdown();
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed and released at http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-spatial/0.9.1-neo4j-1.8.2/

Issue 93: https://github.com/neo4j/spatial/issues/93

Comment: This fix for 1.8.2 is not available for 1.9. I downloaded neo4j spatial plugin here: http://dist.neo4j.org.s3.amazonaws.com/spatial/neo4j-spatial-0.11-neo4j-1.9-server-plugin.zip

and for the 0.11-neo4j-1.9 build, I am getting the same error in the question title, when I try to create a spatial index using the REST api as given here: http://neo4j.github.io/spatial/#rest-api-create-a-spatial-index.